# is there any Seed-stack training available

Tags: seedstack

I'm new to seed stack framework and looking for some training's or step by step tutorials.

If anyone will help to understand this framework it would be a big help

If you will help me with below code example will be really appreciated

```
•   Java  Config Example [Jobs and Steps config]
•   Learn to create and configure  batch’s JobExecutionListener (before and after job), StepExecutionListener (before and after step), ItemReadListener, ItemProcessListener, ItemWriteListener and SkipListener implementations with example.
•   Batch ItemProcessor Example
•   FlatFileItemReader – Read CSV Example
•   FlatFileItemWriter – Write to CSV File
•   MultiResourceItemReader – Read Multiple CSV Files Example
•   Delete or Archive Files After Processing
•   CSV to Database – Java Annotation Config Example
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you've already looked into but I recommend to go with [the tutorial](http://seedstack.org/docs/basics/) first. It will start with the basics and let you have a superficial look at various topics. Follow it carefully.

Then read the [core docs](http://seedstack.org/docs/core/) which explain basic topics (startup, shutdown, config, logging, security, REST, Web apps, ...).

When needed you can go further with:

- [Business docs](http://seedstack.org/docs/business/) which explain how tactical Domain-Driven Design can be used to write you business code (model, logic, interfaces).
- [Maven plugin docs](http://seedstack.org/docs/maven-plugin/) which explain how you can execute and package your apps along with executing various tools.
- [Guides](http://seedstack.org/guides/) to learn about a particular topic.
- [The add-on library](http://seedstack.org/addons/) to extend SeedStack with various technologies and products. Each add-on has it's own docs.
- [The Javadoc](http://seedstack.org/javadoc/) for specifics about Java APIs.
- [Code samples](http://seedstack.org/docs/samples/).

If you have any *specific* question, feel free to ask it here.

Comment: @ Adrien LAUER thanks for your replay , really appreciated. Yes i have gone through the basic tutorial from official website. I'm specifically looking for Batch implementation and  micro services Implementation.   with help of seedstack framework. where i can get the practical implementation code samples where i can understand more about framework . and one more thing need to know do we have any video training available for the same?

Comment: i have updated my question with some topic list , need some sample code for more understanding . can you please comment on the same